# Excel take apart address cities with districts correctly?

Tags: excel

How to take apart addresses in Excel?

I have addresses like:

- Zipcode always 4 digits
- But in cities like Budapest and London, there is a district number like XV. and V.
- I know the city names witch contains district numbers.

```
5555 London XV. Apple Street 77.
6666 Budapest V. Banana Street 6.
7777 Southampton Big street 5.
8888 Southampton Small street 6.
```

***Text To Columns Excel***

Unfortunately, this format like that when I use space as delimiter:

```
5555 |London      |XV.  |Apple Street |77.
6666 |Budapest    |V.   |Banana Street |6.
7777 |Southampton |Big  |street |5.
8888 |Southampton |Small| street |6.
```

If I use space and dot as a delimiter still not works good.

***I want this structure:***

```
5555 |London      XV.  |Apple Street |77.
6666 |Budapest    V.   |Banana Street |6.
7777 |Southampton      |Big  |street |5.
8888 |Southampton      |Small| street |6.
```

Which functions shall I use ?

Comment: Can you please share an image of the (sample) data, available AS-IS so that we can find a way to help you?

Comment: In your desired structure, in the last two lines you have a pipe (`|`) between the street name and the word `street` but not in the first two rows where `Street` is capitalized.  Is there a reason for that?  Or is it a typo?  Also, in your desired structure, you have added spaces between the city name and district number, as well as at the end of the city name section.  Again, is that deliberate?  Will all of your cities have a single name?

Comment: In general, with this kind of problem, you'll need a table listing all of the cities and city+districtCode to use to obtain the splitting that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine this is not what you are looking for, but when I needed to deal with such situations in the past, I did the following:

```
Replace "London XV" by "London_XV"   (using an underscore or a hyphen)
Replace "Budapest V" by "Budapest_V" (same thing)
...
(You can easily do this in a simple text editor, like Notepad, Notepad++, ...)

Then you do the Text To Columns (or you do this while importing the textfile).

Afterwards, you replace "London_XV" back by "London XV" and "Budapest_V" by "Budapest V", ...
```

Good luck